# mysql 5.5 character encoding in Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I recently setup mysql 5.5.20 database in Amazon RDS with movable type but actual character encoding doesn't take effect. I change the parameter group setting to utf8 like below.

```
character-set-client-handshake = yes
character_set_client  = utf8
character_set_connection = utf8
character_set_database = utf8
character_set_filesystem = binary
character_set_results = utf8
character_set_server = utf8
collation_connection = utf8_general_ci
collation_server = utf8_general_ci
init_connect = SET NAMES utf8
```

When I build Movable Type 5.13 database table encodeing is **cp1252_West_Europe** and collation is labeled **latin1_swedish_ci** but actually should be UTF-8 Unicode and utf8_general_ci

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just Movable Type that's creating the fields with that encoding?

Comment: I tried CREATE TABLE manually and still gives me cp1252_West_European and latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I got it.

RDS by default sets its encoding to latin8 ignoring the parameter group that you created.  So I just needed to delete the first DB that you have to set from the AWS dashboard.

Comment: You don't need to delete the DB. You can just switch the Paramter Group and RDS dashboard will ask you to reboot the instance.

Comment: Oh, almost forgot, you can switch the Parameter Group by selecting "Modify" in the Instance Actions dropdown.